# HTMLAudioElement and authorization

Tags: javascript, audio, cookies, authorization, media-player

I'm trying to implement an authorization scheme for streaming audio with `HTMLAudioElement` that allows users to stream audio, but not to download it.

`HTMLAudioElement` can be given either an URL via `src` or an object via `srcObj`. The object may be a `MediaStream`, `MediaSource`, `File`, or `Blob`. I've searched MDN and the net for the ability to tell the browser the use an `Authorization` header in the request it's going to send, but none of the objects mentioned seem to allow for this.

I can't use `fetch` either, because streaming means audio should start right away, without having to wait until the full blow has been downloaded. I don't think `fetch` can be used with streaming.

So, the only solution I have found is that I first get a token from an endpoint `auth.php`, and then pass that token as a GET parameter to my audio endpoint, like this:

```
https://example.com/audio.php?album=1&song=4&token=thetokengoeshere
```

Unfortunately, this means users can copy the url from the browser's network tab and use that to download the audio.

I noticed that the browser sends the cookies from the server (PHPSESSID) along with the audio request, and if I set `audio.crossOrigin = 'use-credentials'`, JS-created cookies are sent as well. Can I use a cookie to prevent users from using the URL in another tab? I don't think so: Cookies are not bound to a particular browser tab, so the browser would send the cookies in the new tab as well. We might consider using a very short-lived token, but that's no good, because audio streaming requires that the browser can use the same url to seek to a position and continue streaming from there.

So, how to do this?

Comment: Just to make sure that you understand this: You can never completely prevent the user from downloading the stream, you can only make it difficult.

Comment: Is that so? I'm aware users can always use the analogue way to get hold of the audio (record while streaming), but I'm not sure if there's no functioning authorization scheme. How do spotify, youtube, soundcloud do it?

Comment: As for youtube and soudcloud there are websites and tools to rip music, as for spotify I am sure there are tool too but I don't know any.